Did I tell the smallest "lie" with my rebid?
New club, new partner, new game, with people I had met for the first time.
Neither vulnerable at matchpoints, I dealt and opened one heart with the following hand:
♠KT84 ♥AK984 ♦K9 ♣J3. Partner responded 1NT (forcing).
I rebid two hearts. Partner raised me to four with J5 of hearts and 9 high card points, which we made, but probably through a misplay on an opponent's part.
One of my opponents accused me of "lying" about a six card suit with my rebid and asked, "What about your three card minor?". When I said, "I had 4-5-2-2," partner said, "I would have bitten the bullet and bid a two card minor." Everyone agreed that the third theoretical possibility, a "reverse" to two spades was "out."
Is two hearts in fact the smallest lie? My suit was led by AK, and I had 14 high card points. Technically, a hand like ♠AJ8 ♥K98642 ♦K9 ♣J3 would fit my bidding better, but perhaps not be as playable. I thought partner's raise was aggressive, it was "successful," and partner got us top scores with several more similarly "stretchy" bids.

It's up to partnership agreement as always, but the most common agreement is that you always rebid 2C on 4=5=2=2 shape.  The reason for this agreement is that 2C is the cheapest bid, so it allows partner the most flexibility in continuations - in particular if partner has a weak hand with a 6 card minor they can get out in 2 of either minor.
In one partnership, I actually play that 2D always promises 4, so one would rebid 2C on 3=5=3=2 or even 4=5=3=1 shape.  (This is alertable.)

With a new partner I'd avoid the 2C rebid; but this auction should be the third one that you discuss with a new partner before pulling the first hand (after responses to 1NT and responses to 2C), for just this reason: knowing which rebid holds all the lies is important for partnership trust.

@ForgetIwaseverhere: I consider rebidding 2C with 4=5=2=2 part of standard 2/1.

Perhaps it's standardized to 2C in recent years, but the lie of 2H was more common than that of 2C where and when I was playing regularly. This can also be a regional issue, and one should be cogniscient of the local preferences.

Note: since the new Alert Procedure removed the "no Flannery exception", 2C on 4=5=2=2 is also Alertable (in the ACBL).  I questioned it during the draft stage, and the removal was deliberate (in exchange for "forcing, could have 4 spades" for the Flannery pairs, I guess).  5 years in, I still forget.  And I bet 70% of the ACBL doesn't know.  Tom: agree, it's still "standard" to bid 2C.

@ForgetIwaseverhere: I'm trying to minimize "mean squared error." A two card minor is "two thirds" of a three card minor, while I consider AKxxx a "5.5" card suit.

@TomAu I'm with you.  I think the rebid of 2H was the least lie / best choice.  Especially with a new partner.
